# Capture part of pdf file in python

Tags: python, image

I have pdf file of two pages and there is a barcode at the top of the first page like that

[image]

Is there a way to capture the barcode only from such scanned pdf file in python? I have searched but didn't find such issue. Can you help me with even any link as a clue and I will study the link and try to implement it by myself?

I find such a code but couldn't modify to crop the top part of the first page only

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

with open("Sample.pdf", "rb") as in_f:
    input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    
    numPages = input1.getNumPages()
    print("Document Has %s pages." % numPages)
    
    for i in range(numPages):
        page = input1.getPage(i)
        print(page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y())
        page.trimBox.lowerLeft = (25, 25)
        page.trimBox.upperRight = (225, 225)
        page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (50, 50)
        page.cropBox.upperRight = (200, 200)
        output.addPage(page)

    with open("Output.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
        output.write(out_f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to detect and extract the barcode it would be easiest to convert the pdfs to images and subsequently run barcode detection on the images. Conversion to images can be done with [pdf2image](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/). A standard way to detect barcodes is using zbar, for example with [pyzbar](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/), but I got no detection results for your image, probably due to the quality of the scan. Alternatively barcodes can be extracted with Opencv. For the working example below I repurposed code from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575039/how-to-crop-detected-barcode-from-image-in-python) post:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

from pdf2image.exceptions import (
    PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
    PDFPageCountError,
    PDFSyntaxError
)

images = convert_from_path('Sample.pdf')

#convert PIL images to cv2
images = [np.array(i)[:, :, ::-1] for i in images]

for nr, image in enumerate(images):
  # convert it to grayscale
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # compute the Scharr gradient magnitude representation of the images
  # in both the x and y direction using OpenCV 2.4
  ddepth = cv2.cv.CV_32F if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.CV_32F
  gradX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth = ddepth, dx = 1, dy = 0, ksize = -1)
  gradY = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth = ddepth, dx = 0, dy = 1, ksize = -1)

  # subtract the y-gradient from the x-gradient
  gradient = cv2.subtract(gradX, gradY)
  gradient = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gradient)

  # blur and threshold the image
  blurred = cv2.blur(gradient, (9, 9))
  (_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

  # construct a closing kernel and apply it to the thresholded image
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 7))
  closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

  # perform a series of erosions and dilations
  closed = cv2.erode(closed, None, iterations = 4)
  closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations = 4)

  # find the contours in the thresholded image, then sort the contours
  # by their area, keeping only the largest one
  cnts = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
  c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]

  # compute the rotated bounding box of the largest contour
  rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
  box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(rect)
  box = np.int0(box)

  # draw a bounding box arounded the detected barcode and display the
  min_y = int(np.min(box[:,-1]))
  max_y = int(np.max(box[:,-1]))
  min_x = int(np.min(box[:,0]))
  max_x = int(np.max(box[:,0]))
  image = image[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x]
  # save cropped image
  cv2.imwrite(f"cropped_{nr}.jpg", image)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The PDF file is only scanned image so the pdf contents is only image and the barcode part is just part of the image inside the PDF. I am not sure if that helps or not. I just need to crop that part. I think the code in the main post is OK but I didn't know how to adjust the numbers to fit my case,

Comment: I need the barcode part with the number below it .. I am interested in the number not in the barcode in fact.

Comment: You'll need to retrieve the image from the pdf in order to do barcode recognition. This can be done with PyPDF2 as per your example, but that is [somewhat cumbersome](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/Scripts/pdf-image-extractor.py). You could run OCR on the image output to get the barcode nr.

Comment: I am not sure. Can you please have a look at the sample pdf https://excel-egy.com/Up/do.php?id=511 .. This may clarify the issue.

Comment: That pdf file works fine on my code. But I guess that's not what you'd like to know. What is your concrete question?

Comment: When I tried the code, I encountered an error `PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?`.

Comment: The pdf2image package relies on poppler-utils: `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and I have used `pip install poppler-utils` and tried again but the same problem is still there.

Comment: I have searched and downloaded poppler for windows then edited that line `images = convert_from_path('Sample.pdf', poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-20.11.0\bin')`. The code now works fine, but as for the output I got two images the first is the barcode without the number below it and the second one is unclear.

Comment: You could add `+30` in max_y and max_x after `box[...]` to widen the crop so it includes the number. The hits from the other page are false positives, so you could also just process `image[0]` rather than both pages.

Comment: Do you mean like that `max_y = int(np.max(box[:,-1])) + 30` or `max_y = int(np.max(box[:,-1]+30))`? and how to get the first image only?